# How to do ceiling in linked list?

Tags: java, symbol-table

I cant figure out how to return the smallest key in the symbol table that is greater than or equal to the key.. if someone can point me in the right direction that would be great because i dont know where to begin

```
public class LinkedListST<Key extends Comparable<Key>, Value> {
    private Node first; 

    // a helper linked list data type
    private class Node {
        private Key key;
        private Value val;
        private Node next;

    public Node(Key key, Value val, Node next)  {
        this.key  = key;
        this.val  = val;
        this.next = next;
    }
}

 public Key ceiling (Key key) {
    Key ceiling = null;
    for(Node x = first; x != null; x = x.next){
        if(first.key.compareTo(ceiling) > 0)
            ceiling = key; 
    }
    return null; //TODO
}
```

Comment: Hint: Iterate the list, comparing each key in the list with the key you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Create a static variable in your `Node` class:

```
private static Key CEILING = null;
```

And then in your constructor, compare every newly added `Key` with the `CEILING`:

```
if(key > CEILING)  // Just algorithm. Use compareTo() method in your case.
    CEILING = key
```

Like this, at the end of filling up your LinkedList, you would have a `key` with the highest value.

OR:

```
if(key < CEILING)
    CEILING = key // for smallest key
```

Comment: hi thanks for the help i have edited my code. i am not sure if my logic for my loop and my if statement is correct

Comment: @yenyen your loop is fine. Just `return ceiling` from the method